# Face recognition system with a sparse dataset

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, data-sets

I have a dataset of 100 ID's, each ID with only a single unique face image. How can I develop an effective face recognition system to recognise only these faces?

I was thinking Deep Learning but the dataset is so sparse. It would be 100 classes each with a single data point (the image).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125252/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61621060/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply transfer learning.  Leverage one of the existing datasets and deep learning networks that can classify faces e.g. celebrities.

Add/remove layers on top of the feature extraction layers and use your small data set.  Provided that the base dataset / network is large and rich enough you should be able to apply it to your dataset.

See https://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/